# Error in amavisd.conf -missing curly or bracket

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, centos6.4, amavis, clamav

I'm currently trying to setup Spam and Virus Filtering on my CentOS 6.4 machine using SpamAssassin and ClamAV. I've installed all necessary packages (SA, ClamAV and Amavisd-new) and configured them. While trying to start amavisd I get the following error:

```
Error in config file "/etc/amavisd.conf": syntax error at /etc/amavisd.conf line 955, at EOF
Missing right curly or square bracket at /etc/amavisd.conf line 955, at end of line
```

I manually checked for open curlies or brackets and even used `perltidy` with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using perltidy on files w/ invalid syntax may yield even more broken output files. Also perltidy doesn't overwrite the source file unless told to.

Did you try to do an

```
perl -c /etc/amavisd.conf
```

?

If this also yields this error you'll have to double check to config file syntax and get somebody to double check it for you.

If this file is fine, then there is probably another issue w/ your installation,

Comment: This is my output: http://pastebin.com/x7i82C3b 
I just did a fresh install. I can't seem to find the source of the error. This makes no sense.